# Sonata Admin: send email after validation

Tags: php, email, symfony, sonata-admin

I am working with symfony2, sonata admin-bundle and mongodb, i just made an interface to add users, how can i send an email when user press create on sonataadmin's web interface, i have to override any class of Sonata-Admin?

#### UPDATE

```
//~/UserAdmin.php
      public function create($object)
        {
            parent::create($object);
    
            // send welcome email to new user
            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject('LOL')
                ->setFrom('no-reply@dummy.com')
                ->setTo('dummy@dummy.com')
                ->setBody('dummy message')
            ;
    
            $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('mailer')->send($message);
        }
```

I had to use `$this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->` to get the container and the mailer.

Comment: What exactly do you want to add as functionality? Send the creator an email or sent to the user you created an email that he has been added?

Comment: send to the user you created an email

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you should not answer the question as a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to override the **create** method in the admin class...

**UserAdmin class:**

```
public function create($object)
{
    parent::create($object);

    // send welcome email to new user
}
```