# Symfony2, Sonata, UserBundle : Send email when user is enable on update

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, sonata-user-bundle, sonata

I would like to be able to send an email to the user when the admin enable the user in Sonata admin panel.

[image]

I have to idea which file i should override or extend.

I suppose it is similar to this [subject](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/issues/155) or this [stack-overflow subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21913356/sonata-admin-send-email-after-validation):

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function create($object)
{
    parent::create($object);

    // send welcome email to new user
}
```

I found the create function in the admin bundle but i suppose it would not be overridden only for the UserBundle. If it is indeed the way to go, how could i specify for the UserBundle only?

For the information I can't find any create or update function in UserBundle. Only in the AdminBundle.

Comment: I would look at EventListener, to avoid making this in the entity.

Comment: That seems a pretty good idea. Do you have any hints how i would listen that specific event?

Comment: Nope sorry, I don't use SonataAdmin, I've just have this hint :P

Comment: Using events is the best way to go since you can re-use them at any place of your app. Here is an example of using the create function though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21913356/sonata-admin-send-email-after-validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will relate to contract event from my gist:
https://gist.github.com/webdevilopers/4eea317ade72a119a72e
Adapt it to your needs. Guess you can simply rename "Contract" to "User".

Then add the event somewhere in your admin class:

```
$event = new ContractEvent($contract);

$dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
$dispatcher->dispatch(
    ContractEvents::CONTRACT_CREATED,
$event
);
```

See the gist for details how to inject SwiftMailer.

Instead of creating your own event you can choose from the events Sonata Admin offers you:
[Admin's documentation - Reference - Events (master)](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/events.html)

Pick up the one that suits your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is way more clear that way :).

I've been trying to override the PreUpdate method from the UserAdmin which is actually working. But your solution seems cleaner.